# jquery check has id always goes to else

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the jfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Vp942/1/

I have a div `campaignDiv` 
and I want when the user clicks out side of it, i want to hide it.

THis is what I tried

```
$(document).bind('click', function (e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.parents().has("#campaignDiv")) { $("#campaignDiv").hide(); } else { console.log("asdf");}
});
```

but for some reason, always the `else` is executed even when I clicked inside the `campaignDiv`

could u help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) returns a jQuery object; when used inside an `if` condition it always evaluates to true even if contains zero elements. And don't confuse yourself that it will return either true or false as same as [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)/[`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

Try,

```
$(document).bind('click', function (e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.parents().find("#campaignDiv").length) { 
        $("#campaignDiv").hide();
    } else { console.log("asdf");}
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vp942/10/)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this one, faster IMO:

```
$(document).bind('click', function (e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.closest('#campaignDiv').length) {
        $("#campaignDiv").hide();
    } else { 
        console.log("asdf");
    }
});
```

The [$.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function will go through the hierarchy (bottom to top) stopping at the first parent matching the selector.

Your modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vp942/11/)